# how to convert integer(months) into human friendly string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to translate a number of months, integer based, into a human friendly string containing information about years. its not easy to explain so I will just provide examples. inputs and outputs I want are:

```
input: 19
output: "1 year, 7 months"

input: 24
output: "2 years"

input: 26
output: "2 years, 2 months"
```

do you know any out of the box solutions? if not, how would you implement it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input = 26
year, month = input.divmod(12)
if month.eql? 0 and year > 1
  puts "#{year} years"
elsif month.eql? 0 and year.eql? 1
  puts "#{year} year"
elsif year > 1
  puts "#{year} years, #{month} month"
else
  puts "#{year} year, #{month} month"
end
```

Output

```
2 years, 2 month
```

Comment: Not sure if your code or output is incorrect but should it not be "2 years, 2 months"?

Comment: There is no such option for me to vote to reopen. And also the OP is not even considering accepting the answer so that question must have been closed.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is tagged with Ruby on Rails, ActiveSupport extensions are available, so this works too:

```rb
number_of_months = 19 # for example

ActiveSupport::Duration.build(number_of_months.months).inspect.gsub(' and',', ')
```

**Edit**
I just noticed that there was a bug in ActiveSupport::Duration version 6.0.2.2 that was fixed sometime prior to version 6.1.0.alpha that caused rounding errors for certain values of `number_of_months`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
num.divmod(12).then { |y, m| [y, m].zip ['years', 'months'] }
              .reject{ |e| e.first.zero? }
              .each{ |e| e.last.delete_suffix!('s') if e.first == 1 }
              .join(' ')
              .tap{ |res| res.replace('0 months') if res.empty? }
```

Samples:

```
[11, 12, 13, 23, 24, 25, 26].each { |n| p [n, n.divmod(12).then.......] } # pseudo

[11, "11 months"]
[12, "1 year"]
[13, "1 year 1 month"]
[23, "1 year 11 months"]
[24, "2 years"]
[25, "2 years 1 month"]
[26, "2 years 2 months"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def pluralize(num, string)
  [num, (num == 1 ? string : "#{string}s")] * ' ' 
end

def humanize_months(months)
  months = input % 12
  years = input / 12
  text = [] 
  text << pluralize(years, 'year') if years > 0
  text << pluralize(months, 'month') if months > 0
  text * ', '
end
```